# Uninitialized constant CreateJob::RestClient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I am trying to get a job to fire off that creates an order in our ERP.

all works just fine directly through the gem, so I started making the job itself.

I have 3 files: erp_order_methods.rb, create_or_update_erp_order.rb order.rb

**erp_order_methods.rb:**

```
module ErpOrderMethods
  # These methods are used by create_or_update_erp_order_job

  def self.include base
  bese.extend ClassMethods
end

module ClassMethods
```

**create_or_update_erp_order_job.rb**

```
class CreateOrUpdateErpOrderJob
  include ErpOrderMethods
  @queue = :priority_queue

 def self.perform(task_id, order_id)
  task = Task.find(task_id)
  order = Order.find(order_id)
  erp_order = order.erp_order
```

**order.rb (model)**

```
def create_or_update_erp_order
  @task = Task.create(
  status: "scheduled",
  description: "Create or Updat Order for Web Order No: #{self.id}",
  system_task: true
)

Resque.enqueue(CreateOrUpdateErpOrderJob, @task.id, self.id)
```

end

When i go to test this, I am getting:
    `General Error: Type - NameError | Message - uninitialized constant CreateOrUpdateErpOrderJob::RestClient`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found the issue after some digging around.

```
def self.include base
  bese.extend ClassMethods
```

`spelling errors: bese => base`

`self.include => self.included`